# Are the distribution of globular cluster systems in giant elliptical galaxies spherical?

Tags: galaxy, globular-clusters

I have been trying to find literature sources on the posted question in the title. The only source I found is from a 1991 review by William Harris which is provided [here](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.aa.29.090191.002551?casa_token=I_%5B%E2%80%A6%5DanDalzF3MZi7sWqbBlOATT0nLp1BhGbjl0tymtZe5Izch_CmgyWJzXzpRw). In the review, the author says the distribution of GCS in spirals is generally spherical but the distributions generally agree with the isophotes of the light-field in giant ellipticals. Given how old the source is, I am wondering if this still generally holds true. If there are any newer sources, it would be great if someone can provide a pointer. Thanks!